# Пропали кнопки в blender

Tags: blender

Начинаю изучать blender и пропали эти кнопки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как их вернуть? Буду благодарна за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Возможно Вы отключили отображение заголовка ( сняли галочку с `Show Header`) в таком случае в правой верхней части вьюпорта вам нужно нажать на маленькую стрелочку вниз (которая возвращает скрытое):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если Вы сделали что-то более сложное и первый способ не помог, можно откатиться к стандартным настройкам `Load Factory Settings`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо в меню `Edit->Preferences...` через нижнюю кнопку бургера `Load Factory Preferences` не забудьте сохранить их там же `Save Preferences`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]